# FIle not deleting in destinaton S3 bucket.Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I enabled CORS on my S3 bucket and when I upload an object to the source bucket it gets replicated to the destination bucket fine. But when I delete the object from the source bucket, it does not get deleted from the destination bucket.

Is this correct behaviour or have I configured something wrong?

Comment: How have you implemented replication between buckets?

Comment: I have set the entire bucket to be replicated and I haven't enabled any encryption on it.Also both the buckets are present in different regions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation for cross-region replication from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-what-is-isnot-replicated.html I found a couple of comments that might explain the behaviour:

> If using latest version of the replication configuration, that is you specify the Filter element in a replication configuration rule, Amazon S3 does not replicate the delete marker.

And another:

> If you specify an object version ID to delete in a DELETE request, Amazon S3 deletes that object version in the source bucket, but it doesn't replicate the deletion in the destination bucket.